# Japanese Ingredient question

Tags: japanese-cuisine, sushi, tuna

I have a recipe I received several years ago from a sushi class I took for spicy tuna rolls. There is two ingredients I can't find when I search the web. They are: KOBASHI and TOBIASHI. Any idea what these are?

Comment: google doesn't return anything sushi related, do you have more info or context on what those ingredients were ?

Comment: could it be a typo for togarashi?  https://www.geniuskitchen.com/about/togarashi-50  (if there's no other heat source, as you mention 'spicy', this is likely it; it might be worth posting the recipe so we can figure out what might be missing)

Comment: Hello Christopher and welcome! Can you please edit your question to include your recipe? More information may garner better answers for you.

Answer (score 2):

I've a feeling one of those items should be Tobiko, flying fish roe. Normally a pale or brightly coloured orange little eggs like this:
[image: tobiko on sushi roll]